# Compare pointer and int number with each other

Tags: c++

In the Omnet++ simulaton I am going to get vehicle information such as ID and their location and save them in 2 diffrent array.
But I don't want to have duplicate informations in array .
I used "if (*(p1+i1)==*f){}" that if there is duplicate information m++ and after that if m>0 the information don't incrise in array.
but it doesn't run in the if (*(p1+i1)==*f){}
How to fix my problem.

```
 int id_array[100];  
Coord  position_array[100];
int n=0;
int *p1;
p1=&id_array[0];
Coord *p2;
p2=&position_array[0];



  for(it = availableCars.begin(); it != availableCars.end(); it++){

   TraCIMobility* my_mobility = TraCIMobilityAccess().get(it->second);
   //get information from tracimobility

   int $id=my_mobility->getId();
   std::cout<<"get id of vehicle="<<$id<<std::endl;

   Coord curr_posion =my_mobility->getCurrentPosition();
   std::cout<<"get currposition of vehicle"<<std::endl;

  // Check that array elements are not duplicate
  if(n>0){
      std::cout<<"i am in if"<<std::endl;
   for(int i1=0;i1<=n;i1++){
       std::cout<<"i am in for"<<std::endl;
       int *f=& $id;
 /***********my problem is here************/

       if (*(p1+i1)==*f){
           m++;
       }
   }
  }


 if(m==0){
           //set id in array
             id_array[n]=$id;

          //set position in array
             position_array[n]=curr_posion;

            n=n+1;
   }
   m=0;

      }
```

please help me to solve my problem .
Thanks.

Comment: int *f=& $id; this is the problem , here you are passing address of $id to pointer f , correct way would be f = & $id;

Comment: I write     int f=& $id; and then  if (*(p1+i1)==f){} , but it gives me an error. "
cannot initialize a variable of type " int with an rvalue of type 'int *' "

Comment: Where is the implementation of `TraCIMobility`? And which line the error message points to?

Comment: Exactly the same line that I changed the code indicates the error.
TraCIMobility is one of the omnet++ classes that gives the moving vehicle information.(I write my code in another class)

Comment: Not sure I'm getting, you're trying to avoid duplication using `if (*(p1+i1)==*f)` statement and yet you do? it seems like it should work. can you please share what's the expected results and you do get?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work
A part of the output that displays the Id : 2401304  
0 ,110864736 ,0, 1,0,12732313, 0, 111969784, 0, 0, 0,1, ,0,0,0, 111969680, 0,10523040,0, 0,0,0, 0, 111969776,0,9995803, 0,1,0,1006869552,32761,-1,-3 ,208,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,110864736,0,111969680,0,83907136, 0, 1647497440, 0
10916640
0
110311104
0
10021206
0
0
0
22
34
40
16
28
46

Comment: @stylo   These outputs are related to id. I don't know why duplicate numbers are in it?   I don't know why there is a negative ID inside it?  I don't know why some ids figures are great ????

Comment: isn't the error at `int $id=my_mobility->getId();` ? What does `my_mobility->getId()` returns?

Comment: First assumption for why some of your ID's are negative is because the `id_array` is defined as an `int` array instead of an `unsigned int`, values bigger than `2147483647` will result as a negative number (read about `two's complement` system)

Comment: @mrazimi  no ,error is this line. if (*(p1+i1)==*f)

Comment: @stylo how can Idefine the id_array with  unsigned int type?

Comment: `unsigned` is a keyword in the C/C++ language which can be used along side any numeric type i.e. `unsigned int` `unsigned long` `unsigned char`

Comment: @stylo Thank you very much.
But how do I remove duplicates?

Comment: @Faezeh, regarding the list of numbers you printed above, did you get them from `id_array` or from `getId` function? just double checking in case you printed the values before the duplication reduction.

Comment: @stylo  I get these aove numbers from id_array

Comment: If that's okay with you, I'd like to see the full code, because it looks like it should work.

Comment: @stylo I apologize, I didn't understand this part  of your sentence." just double checking in case you printed the values before the duplication reduction"

Comment: @Faezeh, I thought that you may have printed that list of numbers for every Id you got from the `getId` function before you assigned them to `id_array` that way in case of duplication you'd still print those values.

Comment: @stylo That's all the code I wrote. I want to get the ID and position from the moving vehicles. And the rest of the code is related to this information. That I still couldn't write.(Omnet++ contains many code and classes that we can use or modify.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
int id_array[100];  
Coord  position_array[100];
//int n=0;                     <---- Causing unreachable check block
int *p1;
p1=&id_array[0];
Coord *p2;
p2=&position_array[0];


m=0;     //   <---- For ensurance

  for(it = availableCars.begin(); it != availableCars.end(); it++){

   TraCIMobility* my_mobility = TraCIMobilityAccess().get(it->second);
   //get information from tracimobility

   int $id=my_mobility->getId();
   std::cout<<"get id of vehicle="<<$id<<std::endl;

   Coord curr_posion =my_mobility->getCurrentPosition();
   std::cout<<"get currposition of vehicle"<<std::endl;

  // Check that array elements are not duplicate
  if(n>0){
      std::cout<<"i am in if"<<std::endl;
   for(int i1=0;i1<=n;i1++){
       std::cout<<"i am in for"<<std::endl;
       int *f=& $id;
 /***********my problem is here************/

       //if (*(p1+i1)==*f){
       //    m++;
       //}

       if ( p1[i1]==*f ){
          m++;
       }

   }
  }


 if(m==0){
           //set id in array
             id_array[n]=$id;

          //set position in array
             position_array[n]=curr_posion;

            n=n+1;
   }
   m=0;

}
```

I wish you success.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance but unfortunately the duplicate elements displayed still

Comment: @Faezeh, Look at `int n=0;`. You should remove this line of code, cause it is always zero and your detection code is unreachable(like m variable, n should be global).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It enters the loop but does not execute the if condition.